# Invalidating a NSTimer from within its invocation method

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, nstimer

I have scheduled a timer using [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:] and want to invalidate it at some point when it fires.

```
- (id)init
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(fired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)fired:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    if (someCondition) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Is this allowed? The documentation states

> You must send this message from the thread on which the timer was installed. If you send this message from another thread, the input source associated with the timer may not be removed from its run loop, which could prevent the thread from exiting properly.

If this is not a proper way to accomplish this task: What is the proper way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fine to invalidate it from the fired method, as the fired method is on the same thread the timer was scheduled on:

> scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:
>
> Creates and returns a new NSTimer object and schedules it on the current run loop in the default mode.

Answer (score 5):

Calling `[timer invalidate]` from within the fire method is just fine, that code will be executed in the same thread as the one used when you created the timer.

The Apple Doc you quoted only warns you that if you create a separate thread and invalidate the timer from it, then, and only then, should expect unpredictable behaviour.

Ex.

```
// Create the background queue
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("do not do this", NULL);

// Start work in new thread
dispatch_async(queue, ^ { 

         // !! do not do this  !!
         if (someCondition) {
                 [yourTimer invalidate];
         }
         // or this
         [self fire:yourTimer];
});

// won’t actually go away until queue is empty
dispatch_release(queue);
```

Comment: this is a way better answer than the one accepted. thanks a bunch